# Splitting a String in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string as follows

```
String s = "3|4||5 9|4 0|0 4 8|..."
```

and I want to split it based on the `"|"` appearances. As such, the split should return

```
["3","4","5 9","4 0,"0 4 8",...]
```

But, in Java,

```
s.split("|") = [, 3, |, 4, ...]
```

In other words, it is splitting by the `""` character, it seems. What is wrong?

Comment: String.split() takes a regular expression, not a plain string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` character has special meaning in regular expressions, so you must escape it with a backslash.  Then you must escape the backslash itself for Java.  Try:

```
s.split("\\|")
```

The [Javadocs for the `Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has lots of details about special characters in regular expressions.  See the "Logical operators" section in that page for what `|` does.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

Since `|` is a meta character,It works when you escape the **special character**.

```
String[] results = result.split("\\|");
```

**or**(personally recommending this)

`String[] result = result.split(Pattern.quote("|"));`

If you use [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Now, `|` will be treated as normal **character** `|` and not as the regex meta char `|`.

[Oracle explained here why `\\`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
 s.split("[|]")
```